# javafx fatal error-exception access violation(problamatic frame: jfxmedia.dll)

Tags: java, javafx, fatal-error

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWl98dhvf8Q I refered this website and added mp4 video to javafx program and i get a fatal error, Some one please help me to clear this runtime error! thank you...

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6b9589ec, pid=1812,
>   tid=5132 JRE version: 7.0_10-b17 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (23.6-b04 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 ) Problematic frame: C
>   [jfxmedia.dll+0x89ec] 
>   Java_com_sun_media_jfxmediaimpl_platform_gstreamer_GSTPlatform_gstInitPlatform+0x218c
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about it ,just report the bug.

It seems you're using Developer preview  JDK 7u10 Build b17 , [7u10 Build b18](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html) is available now , install it may be that bug was fixed! . But i suggest to use Stable release from oracle [Java SE 7u9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: thank you for replying but i have tried both jdk 7u10 build b18 and java se 7u9 but i get the same error again..i don't know how to solve this..i am fed up with it!

Comment: are you using 64 bit version?

Comment: no 32 bit version..can you help me to modify the code so that i shall load mp4 file in someother way

Comment: try media samples in ensemble app ,http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Media/Advanced%20Media

Comment: thank you i tried http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Media/Overlay Media Player this prog on changing the url as String MEDIA_URL = "file://C:/Users/prem/IdeaProjects/OverlayMedia/trailer/sintel.mp4";I get an error Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE : C at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:380) at OverlayMediaPlayer.init(OverlayMediaPlayer.java:60) 8 more...